# How to send/receive messages through a web socket on windows phone 8 using the class ClientWebSocket?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, websocket

The web socket is written in javascript by my colleague. I managed to connect. First of all I have to log in on the application using a test account. I have to send the email and password through a json. I have installed the Json.Net packet using NuGet.

Some code that I found on my reaserch is this, but I do not understand how to send my data using that segment.

```
var buffer = new byte[1024];
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
webSocket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
```

Of course, I can use an object

```
User user=new User();
user.Email="bla@bla.com";
user.Password="pass";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

But it will not be of any use because the method SendAsync accepts only byte type on segment.

All I want is to send that data, and if log in succeeds, I should receive other data (in Json format) about the user.

As a side note, I am quite new to web sockets, I used http protocols from ASP.NET WEB API 2.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have no idea about Windows Phone 8, but by the code you pasted it seems similar to the regular .NET `ClientWebSocket`, so here you have some examples:

```
public static Task SendString(ClientWebSocket ws, String data, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
    return ws.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellation);
}

public static async Task<String> ReadString(ClientWebSocket ws)
{
    ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

    WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        do
        {
            result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
        }
        while (!result.EndOfMessage);

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

If something does not compile or exists in WP8, just find an equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Meanwhile I figured out (I wrote webSockcetObject.Send(jsonObject)  and that's all). I've tried to delete the question ... but it sill appears on site, probably stackoverflow webapplication uses a soft delete. Anyway your solution is correct, and I would vote up you answer but I don't have enough reputation. The best I can do is to approve it and say thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

@vtortola is a working example in case your data comes in multiple segmented messages, but if all data comes in a single message you don't need all those streams to read the message, you just need to do this:

```
public static async Task<String> ReadString(ClientWebSocket socket)
{
    var reciveBuffer = new byte[32000]; 
        
    var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(reciveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);

    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
    {
         await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
    }            
    
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reciveBuffer , 0,  result.Count);
}
```

If your message is splited in multiple segments or you don't know how your message is comming then you have to do like @vtortola

Also if you want to keep receiving messages you can do a while and call ReadString inside, like this:

```
while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var msg = ReadString(socket)
    
    //do something with your message...
}
```